# day is out of range for month: February 29,2016 dateutil - Leap year issue

Tags: python, datetime, python-dateutil

**Code:**

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
dates = parse('February 29,2016').strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print(dates)
```

**Error:**

'''
day is out of range for month: February 29,2016
'''

It seems like leap year is not considered here. Can anyone help me detect 29 February 2016 in the format of 2016-02-29

library versions:
python-dateutil - 2.8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not a supported date format.  If you change it to the 28th, you'll notice the year it captures is the current year, not 2016, hence the error.

```
parse('February 28,2016')
```

Output

```
datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 28, 0, 0)
```

If you add a space after the comma, it becomes a supported format and successfully parses.

```
parse('February 29, 2016')
```

Output

```
datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 29, 0, 0)
```